# Graphviz .dot output with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, graphviz, dot

I have created part of a python program which takes input from user and generates a .dot file to draw a finite automata graph corresponding to certain inputs. The GUI of the program is built on the Tkinter library.

I would like to know if there is a way to convert the .dot file into a PNG file or something I can display in a Tkinter window, as the only way I know of requires explicit commands in CMD:

```
dot output.dot -Tpng -o image.png
```

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run arbitrary commands from within Python with [`subprocess.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run).